# Strange MS SQL Server behavior / Performance issue

Tags: java, sql-server, multithreading, indexing, query-performance

I have a strange behavior on response time for a very simple query. All researches so far didn't show up any help or even hint, what could be wrong here.

I have a table inside my database which is used for storing chains of signed objects. I have different chains, and beside the data to be signed there are some metadata fields. The simplified CREATE statement looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SomeTable](
    [id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [user] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [someType] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [someId] [bigint] NULL,
    [someDescription] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [processName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [taskId] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [data] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [signature] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [signedFormat] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [keyVersion] [int] NULL,
    [predecessorId] [bigint] NULL,
    [chainName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [date] [bigint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SomeTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

There are INDEXES of course:

- Primary key is 'id'
- One ASC and one DESC on 'date'
- One on 'chainname'
- One on 'someDescription '
- One on 'someId'

all are non-unique, non-clustered, except the primary, of course.

Meanwhile, this table got rather big - well, at least relatively. The complete database is about 100 GB of size and this table consumes half of it. The index-space has grown to use 7.5 GB already. Index statistics are up-to-date.

I'm writing into this table using a multi-threaded Java-Application having a (Hikari-)JDBC-ConnectionPool.

So, what causes me headache is, that trying to create a new chain is taking ages, although it shouldn't.
I'm using the javax.persistency classes for encapsulating the data-access. Each thread of my app is trying to create a new chain on startup of the app, and again at two well-defined steps during the app is running.

The standard behavior of the classes, encapsulating the access to this table is, that when trying to add more entries to it, it tries to figure out, whether a chain with the given name is already existing. If so, the last entry is loaded to continue the chain, otherwise a new one created. This object is than used for adding more entries to this chain.

However, as my use-case is somehow special I'm assuring by using unique names (including a time-stamp and some random info) for the chainnames that the chains I try to create are not existing. So I start a new chain on startup for each thread, using this until one of the two well-defined steps is entered, which causes new chains again. So, each thread is creating exactly three chains during its life-time.

Anyway, the same standard behavior applies to my usage of the classes, so, the app tries to lookup for the latest entry of an non-existing chain. This should be rather fast, as there are indexes on the relevant columns. This is the executed statement:

```
select top(1) * from SomeTable s where s.chainName = '<someNotExistingName>' order by s.date, s.id desc
```

When executing this statement in Management Console, it is very fast and returns an empty result in less than a second.
On startup, each thread (10-15, depends) is requesting a fresh chain nearly at the same time. Trying to simulate this 'concurrent access' using console still shows fast response times.

But, on app-startup, the behavior is like if someone is asking for the head of an existing chain, which turns out, that even when executed on Console is taking ages. I was waiting for 48 Minutes on console for one such query, which is unbelievable, tbh.
Looking at the memory-consumption during this waiting time, it looks like if the whole table is loaded into RAM, and not only the index is scanned!

I monitored the startup of the app using SQL Profiler, but I couldn't find a 'faulty' or guilty statement. Maybe I'm using the wrong setting for Profiling? I was recording one session using the default-template, and another one using the "Duration"-template.

I'm running out of ideas what I should looking at to find out, what is causing this issue. But I notice it's getting worse as the table gets bigger. Meanwhile, it takes up to 3 hours(!!) waiting for a thread to return having his chain available :(

Looking desperately for some hints!

Best regards,
Andreas

Comment: Could it be parameter sniffing ? Could it be locking ? Or maybe share the execution plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'parameter sniffing'?
I don't think that locking is an issue. I didn't see locked resources in Analyzer that should cause issues here.
Sharing the plan would be an option - however, which plan to share? All statements I start in console are served very fast. How do I get and share a plan from statement executed from my app?

Comment: [sp_whoisactive](https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive) has an option to see the exection plan as wel as blocked_by_session_id. [parameter sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/) see the url.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following query because your

the query could not use any index seek operator the index scan operator will read all index pages.

```
select top(1) * from SomeTable s where s.chainName = '<someNotExistingName>' order by s.date, s.id desc
```

[image: Execution Plan]
However, the following query has more chances to use your indexes.

```
SELECT *
FROM(SELECT *, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            ORDER BY s.date, 
                     s.id DESC) AS RowNr
     FROM SomeTable s
     WHERE s.chainName = '<someNotExistingName>') AS TMP_TBL
WHERE RowNr = 1;
```

[image]